# Java expression language error ";" expected

Tags: java

OK I'm a beginner and I have to fix this java expression language code to work in my system (Windchill), but looks like I am missing something in the syntax:

```
    LWCNormalizedObject lwc = new LWCNormalizedObject(cr, null, null, null);
    lwc.load(wt.change2.WTChangeRequest2.theCategory);
    Object bUnit = lwc.get(wt.change2.WTChangeRequest2.theCategory);
    If ((bUnit.toString()).equals("PRODUCT_IMPROVEMENT")) {
        wt.team.Team team = (wt.team.Team) ( (wt.workflow.engine.WfProcess) self.getObject() ).getTeamId().getObject();
        java.util.Enumeration principals = team.getPrincipalTarget(wt.project.Role.toRole("Product Manager"));
        while(principals.hasMoreElements()) 
        { 
            wt.org.WTPrincipal wtprincipal = ((wt.org.WTPrincipalReference)principals.nextElement()).getPrincipal(); 
            System.out.println("principal = " + wtprincipal.getPrincipalDisplayIdentifier()); 
            wt.team.TeamHelper.service.addRolePrincipalMap(wt.project.Role.toRole("Change Admin II "),wtprincipal, team ); 
        }
    }
```

I am having the error at the line 4:

```
    If ((bUnit.toString()).equals("PRODUCT_IMPROVEMENT")) {
```

Any help will be highly appreciated =D

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if` instead of `If`?

Comment: Its always better to do if ("PRODUCT_IMPROVEMENT".equals(bUnit.toString())) {} to avoid null pointer exception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`If` should be lowercase.

`if ((bUnit.toString()).equals("PRODUCT_IMPROVEMENT")) {`